# How do I add a Polly policy to a Refit Client created with a factory?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, polly, retry-logic, refit

I have a refit client (`IMyRefitClient`) that returns

```
Task<ApiResponse<ADomainModel>>
```

I can't inject this refit client in Program.cs with `HostBuilder.ConfigureServices` because the url isn't known until runtime. Therefore, I'm using a factory class like:

```
return RestService.For<IMyRefitClient>(hostUrl);
```

I know how to add a policy in `ConfigureServices`. It would look like:

```
services.AddRefitClient<IMyRefitClient>()
        .AddPolicyHandler(PollyHelpers.GetRetryPolicy());
```

Is there a way that I can add this policy when using the factory class?

Comment: You can define or retrieve the policies inside the `IMyRefitClient` implementation. If you want to register the policies into the DI then take a look at the [`PolicyRegistry`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyRegistry) class and `IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string>` interface.

Comment: Did the proposed classes/interfaces solve your problem? Shall I leave a post to further elaborate?

Comment: Using those has indeed worked, thanks @PeterCsala!

Comment: Awesome. Shall I leave a post to close this question?

Comment: @PeterCsala I'm not too familiar with stackoverflow etiquette with accepted answer gone so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polly has a concept of [`PolicyRegister`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/PolicyRegistry), which is basically a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IsPolicy>>` collection.

So, it is a container where you can register policies with arbitrary names:

```
var register = new PolicyRegistry()
{
    { "CB_aware_Retry", GetRetryPolicy() },
    { "500_aware_CB", GetCircuitBreakerPolicy() },
    { "Retry_CB_combined", Policy.WrapAsync(GetRetryPolicy(), GetCircuitBreakerPolicy()) }
};
```

On the `ServiceCollection` [you can register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyservicecollectionextensions.addpolicyregistry?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) a new container or an existing one:

```
services.AddPolicyRegistry(registry)
```

You can access the policies by relying on the [`IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry`](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/174cc53e17bf02da5e1f2c0d74dffb4f23aa99c0/src/Polly/Registry/IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry.cs):

```
public class MyRefitClient 
{
    private readonly IAsyncPolicy<ApiResponse<ADomainModel>>> combined;
    public MyRefitClient(..., IReadOnlyPolicyRegistry<string> registry, ...)
    {
       ...
       combined = registry.Get<IAsyncPolicy<ApiResponse<ADomainModel>>>>("Retry_CB_combined");
    } 
}
```

Comment: Still confused on how to use this with Refit. Would using PolicyRegistry require getting the policy and wrapping it around every Refit call? For example, `policy.Execute(() => refitService.getCustomers(...))`

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers Yes, the above code requires you to explicitly call the `Execute`/`ExecuteAsync` methods. If you can register your Refit client inside your `ConfigureServices` with `AddRefitClient` then you can call `AddPolicyHandler`. With that approach the underlying `DelegatingHandler` will call the `Execute`/`ExecuteAsync` on your behalf.